# App Engine Starts Compute Engine Instance - IllegalAccessError

Tags: google-app-engine, google-compute-engine, illegalaccessexception

haven't seen any others who have run into same problem as myself so posting to hopefully get an answer. I have an app engine that uses an API to have a list of asteroids and can add and retrieve asteroids. Now I want to kick off a compute engine instance when adding a new asteroid that will make some calculations and send an answer back to the app engine.

Right now I have:

```
String projectID = "better-world-175517";
String zone = "us-east1-c";

Compute computeService = createComputeService();
Compute.Instances.List request = computeService.instances().list(projectID, zone);
InstanceList listResponse;
listResponse = request.execute();

for(Instance instance : listResponse.getItems())
{
    System.out.println(instance);
}
```

and this is my createComputeService() method:

```
public static Compute createComputeService() throws IOException, GeneralSecurityException {
    HttpTransport httpTransport = GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport();
    JsonFactory jsonFactory = JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance();

    GoogleCredential credential = GoogleCredential.getApplicationDefault();
    if (credential.createScopedRequired()) {
      credential =
          credential.createScoped(Arrays.asList("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform"));
    }

    return new Compute.Builder(httpTransport, jsonFactory, credential)
        .setApplicationName("test_BetterWorld/1.0")
        .build();
  }
```

But I have not been able to figure out this error log I am getting, it is not providing much information:

```
SEVERE: exception occurred while calling backend method
java.lang.IllegalAccessError: com/google/appengine/repackaged/com/google/common/base/Platform
    at com.google.appengine.repackaged.com.google.common.base.Ticker$1.read(Ticker.java:69)
    at com.google.appengine.repackaged.com.google.common.base.Stopwatch.elapsedNanos(Stopwatch.java:181)
    at com.google.appengine.repackaged.com.google.common.base.Stopwatch.elapsed(Stopwatch.java:194)
    at com.google.appengine.repackaged.com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LoadingValueReference.elapsedNanos(LocalCache.java:3665)
    at com.google.appengine.repackaged.com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.getAndRecordStats(LocalCache.java:2381)
    at com.google.appengine.repackaged.com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.loadSync(LocalCache.java:2336)
    at com.google.appengine.repackaged.com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.lockedGetOrLoad(LocalCache.java:2294)
    at com.google.appengine.repackaged.com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.get(LocalCache.java:2207)
    at com.google.appengine.repackaged.com.google.common.cache.LocalCache.get(LocalCache.java:4062)
    at com.google.appengine.repackaged.com.google.common.cache.LocalCache.getOrLoad(LocalCache.java:4066)
    at com.google.appengine.repackaged.com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LocalLoadingCache.get(LocalCache.java:4995)
    at com.google.appengine.repackaged.com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LocalLoadingCache.getUnchecked(LocalCache.java:5001)
    at com.google.appengine.api.appidentity.AppIdentityServiceImpl.getAccessToken(AppIdentityServiceImpl.java:272)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.extensions.appengine.auth.oauth2.AppIdentityCredential.intercept(AppIdentityCredential.java:98)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.extensions.appengine.auth.oauth2.AppIdentityCredential$AppEngineCredentialWrapper.intercept(AppIdentityCredential.java:243)
    at com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest.execute(HttpRequest.java:868)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:419)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:352)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.execute(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:469)
    at com.example.b612.AsteroidList.insertAsteroid(AsteroidList.java:94)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.agent.runtime.Runtime.invoke(Runtime.java:128)
    at com.google.api.server.spi.SystemService.invokeServiceMethod(SystemService.java:351)
    at com.google.api.server.spi.handlers.EndpointsMethodHandler$RestHandler.handle(EndpointsMethodHandler.java:119)
    at com.google.api.server.spi.handlers.EndpointsMethodHandler$RestHandler.handle(EndpointsMethodHandler.java:102)
    at com.google.api.server.spi.dispatcher.PathDispatcher.dispatch(PathDispatcher.java:49)
    at com.google.api.server.spi.EndpointsServlet.service(EndpointsServlet.java:71)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:511)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1166)
    at com.google.appengine.api.socket.dev.DevSocketFilter.doFilter(DevSocketFilter.java:74)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.ResponseRewriterFilter.doFilter(ResponseRewriterFilter.java:134)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.HeaderVerificationFilter.doFilter(HeaderVerificationFilter.java:34)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.api.blobstore.dev.ServeBlobFilter.doFilter(ServeBlobFilter.java:63)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.TransactionCleanupFilter.doFilter(TransactionCleanupFilter.java:48)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.StaticFileFilter.doFilter(StaticFileFilter.java:122)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerModulesFilter.doDirectRequest(DevAppServerModulesFilter.java:366)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerModulesFilter.doDirectModuleRequest(DevAppServerModulesFilter.java:349)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerModulesFilter.doFilter(DevAppServerModulesFilter.java:116)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:388)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:418)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppEngineWebAppContext.handle(DevAppEngineWebAppContext.java:95)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.JettyContainerService$ApiProxyHandler.handle(JettyContainerService.java:508)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(HttpConnection.java:923)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:547)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:212)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)
    at org.mortbay.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:409)
    at org.mortbay.thread.QueuedThreadPool$PoolThread.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:582)

Aug 11, 2017 11:44:58 AM com.google.appengine.tools.development.AbstractModule shutdown
INFO: Shutting down module instance default
Shutting down.
```

I know the problem lies in the "request.execute()" but I'm unsure how to fix this. I can post more snippits of code if needed. I know it is possible to do, just think I shouldn't use the computeService or something.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved this issue. Turned out to be a java compatability problem. The previous app engine used java 1.7, but I needed to upgrade to java 1.8. I just didn't get an error until this point.